# How to translate "engage in healthy behavior"?

Tags: phrase

The full sentence is

> .... there are 40 building blocks every child needs to grow and
> mature. And the more of these Assets a child has in her life, the more
> likely she is to engage in healthy behaviors while veering away from
> those that are unhealthy.

Besides, "assets" is normally translated to "资产", however it doesn't feel like fitting in here. How about "要素"？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a child psychologist, nor am I too sure of the context.

The English is not so good, the translation will also be bad. This is ambiguous:

> there are 40 building blocks every child needs to grow and mature.

A child can grow and mature, a building block cannot 'grow and mature', nor can a child 'grow and mature' building blocks. But, yes, every child must needs 'grow and mature.' (Some just get bigger! :))

Possibly, you mean:

There are 40 (personality) building blocks every child needs to acquire in order to grow and mature.

There are forty personality factors every child needs to acquire in order to grow and mature.
每个孩子在成长到成熟的过程中都会受到四十个必要的个性因素的影响。

The more of these personality building blocks a child has in her life,
一个孩子在成长中所拥有的筑造这些个性的基石越多，

the more likely she is to behave in a socially acceptable way,
她就越有可能步入正轨，

and not indulge in improper behaviour.
而不会误入歧途。

Answer (score 1):

In the context of educating a child to have a healthy behavior, I would translate the following sentence as:

"...the more likely she is to **engage in healthy behaviors**..."

“...越倾向于**养成好习惯**..."

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"assets" here refers to "building blocks" which is a metaphor for 基础 (basis) -->**基础條件** (basic conditions)

> the more of these [**Assets**] a child has in her life, the more likely she is to [**engage in**] healthy behaviors

> 一个孩童的生活中拥有越多这种[**基础条件**]，就越有可能[**奉行**]健康的行为

*奉行 = to pursue*